# Single object as multiple function inputs

Tags: r

Suppose you have the following function:

```
fxn <- function(x, y, z) {
  x + y + z
}
```

Is it possible to reference multiple columns at once when calling this function? The following code provides an error `Error in fxn(df[cols]) : argument "y" is missing, with no default`

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2), b = c(3,4), c = c(5,6))
cols <- c("a", "b", "c")
df$d <- fxn(df[cols])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you change your input to a list instead of a vector. Also, since you cant sum characters, I've changed the example to use integers.

Essentially, `do.call` allows you to supply your function args as a list

```
fxn <- function(x, y, z) {
  sum(x, y, z)
}

cols <- list(1, 2, 2)

do.call(fxn, cols)
```

Comment: Thanks Connor, I forgot to include the dataframe in my example. I can't seem to incorporate your solution into a vectorized version, do you have any advice on how to incorporate `do.call` when applying the function to vectors?